# Java Set - Which is faster Set.add() or Set.addAll()?

Tags: java, collections, set

`Set` maintains the unique records and update the existing record if an existing element is tried to be duplicated.

Consider below two scenarios. Which you think will be faster and more efficient code between the two?

**Scenario 1: Using addAll()**

```
Set<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>();
uniqueSet = getSomedata(param1);
uniqueSet.addAll( getSomedata(param2) );
```

Here `getSomedata()` just returns collection of data, no special logic in that method.

**Scenario 2: Using add()**

```
Set<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>();
getSomedata(param1, uniqueSet);
getSomedata(param2, uniqueSet );
```

Here `getSomedata()` is as below

```
void getSomedata(String param, Set<String> uniqueSet){
    while (someCollection.hasNext()){
        uniqueSet.add( someCollection.get() );
    }
}
```

Comment: look at the implementation, it's in the src.zip that comes with the JDK. If you properly set up your IDE you should be able to view it there.

Comment: First, the first snippet shouldn't create a useless empty HashSet. Second, what you should strive for is not performance. The difference between those two is probably insignificant. What you should strive for is readability and maintainability. I expect a method named getSomedata() to return some data. Not to take a Set as argument, fill it, and return nothing. What if you want to add the data to a List instead of a Set instead? Or if you just want to iterate over it? The first one is much more natural and easy to understand and use.

Comment: @JBNizet, actually in my application, I am reading a huge data from files exposed from a server. Lines within a file is unique but can be duplicated in multiple files. After collecting data from all files, I just need to process only the unique records. As you know, List does not enforce uniqueness. Hence I am going with Set.

Comment: The time spent in IO is probably much bigger than the time spent in dealing with sets. Use what you find the most readable, and optimize only if needed, and where needed.

Answer (score 2):

`addAll` basically iterates over the collection it's given and calls `add` on every method. Here's the way OpenJDK8 implements it:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    boolean modified = false;
    for (E e : c)
        if (add(e))
            modified = true;
    return modified;
}
```

But as a general rule of thumb, you shouldn't try to invent the wheel unless you're absolutely sure you can invent a better one.

Comment: Just for reference, JDK 7 is the same.

Comment: As far as I understand, the question is not really about addAll() vs. add(), but about each method call creating its own small set and then adding them all to a unique big one, vs. creating a unique set and have the method add the data to this unique set.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is incomplete. Let’s complete it with the actual alternatives.

First, you have a method which populates a provided `Set`:

```
void getSomedata(String param, Set<String> uniqueSet)
```

which has to be used like

```
Set<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>();
getSomedata(param1, uniqueSet);
getSomedata(param2, uniqueSet);
```

The alternative is to have a method which returns a new `Set`:

```
Set<String> getSomedata(String param)
```

which you can use like

```
Set<String> uniqueSet = getSomedata(param1);
uniqueSet.addAll( getSomedata(param2) );
```

in this case, you are ignoring how the method `getSomedata` will create and populate the `Set` that it will return. Obviously, unless it creates a custom `Set` implementation projecting source data, it has to create a `Set` and populate it with elements before returning it.

In other words, it doesn’t matter, how `addAll` is implemented, at the time you are going to invoke it, this solution has already performed the same work as the other alternative, as it already has added all elements to a `Set`. So, even if `addAll` of a particular `Set` implementation has optimizations, it’s work adds to the already performed work of individually adding all elements to a `Set`.

---

Still, the rule that you shouldn’t worry about performance unless there is a real performance problem applies. The involved I/O might outweigh it all. Or the unpredictability of the effects of hotspot optimization and memory management might change it all. If you think, `getSomedate` returning a new `Set` is cleaner (that would be reasonable), use it.

---

As an addendum, I simplified a bit. A `HashSet` is `O(1)` only in theory, but will perform different when there are hash collisions and in the case `TreeSet`s are used, which have `O(log n)` time complexity, the different size of the sets has an effect, thus the alternatives, operating on sets of different size, are not exactly comparable, depending on which `Set` implementations are used and other surrounding context. But the tendency is still the same, especially as in most cases, there are no optimized `addAll` implementations (`EnumSet` might be the only exception).